# Replace a word or set of letters from a string in a dataframe only if the string starts with that word

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have the following toy model `df`:

```
Line          Sentence

1             A MAN TAUGHT ME HOW TO DANCE.
2             WE HAVE TO CHOOSE A CAKE. 
3             X RAYS CAN BE HARMFUL.
4             MY HERO IS MALCOLM X FROM THE USA.
5             THE BEST ACTOR IS JENNIFER A FULTON. 
6             A SOUND THAT HAS A BIG IMPACT.
```

If I were to do the following:

```
df['Sentence'] = df['Sentence'].str.replace('A ',' ')
```

This would remove all characters `'A '` from all sentences. However, I only need the `'A '` removed from string sentences that start with `'A '`. Similarly, I would like to remove the `'X '` from Line 3, and not from Malcolm X  in Line 4.

The final output df should look like the following:

```
Line          Sentence

1             MAN TAUGHT ME HOW TO DANCE.
2             WE HAVE TO CHOOSE A CAKE. 
3             RAYS CAN BE HARMFUL.
4             MY HERO IS MALCOLM X FROM THE USA.
5             THE BEST ACTOR IS JENNIFER A FULTON. 
6             SOUND THAT HAS A BIG IMPACT.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```py
df["Sentence"] = df["Sentence"].str.replace(r"^(?:A|X)(?=\s)", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Line                              Sentence
0     1           MAN TAUGHT ME HOW TO DANCE.
1     2             WE HAVE TO CHOOSE A CAKE.
2     3                  RAYS CAN BE HARMFUL.
3     4    MY HERO IS MALCOLM X FROM THE USA.
4     5  THE BEST ACTOR IS JENNIFER A FULTON.
5     6          SOUND THAT HAS A BIG IMPACT.
```

Comment: what if I want to remove all the leading alphabets and not just A or X?

Comment: @JodeCharger100 You can use something like `df["Sentence"].str.replace(r"^(?:[A-Z]+)(?=\s)", "", regex=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex to match only start of strings:

```
df['Sentence'] = df['Sentence'].str.replace(r'^([AX] )', '', regex=True)
```

`df`:

```
   Line                              Sentence
0     1           MAN TAUGHT ME HOW TO DANCE.
1     2             WE HAVE TO CHOOSE A CAKE.
2     3                  RAYS CAN BE HARMFUL.
3     4    MY HERO IS MALCOLM X FROM THE USA.
4     5  THE BEST ACTOR IS JENNIFER A FULTON.
5     6         SOUND THAT HAS A BIG IMPACT.
```

Answer (score 2):

str.replace, startofstring,value, space. Code below

```
df.Sentence==df.Sentence.str.replace('^A\s+|^X\s+', '')
       
          

                   Sentence
0          MAN TAUGHT ME HOW TO DANCE.
1            WE HAVE TO CHOOSE A CAKE.
2                 RAYS CAN BE HARMFUL.
3   MY HERO IS MALCOLM X FROM THE USA.
4  HE BEST ACTOR IS JENNIFER A FULTON.
5         SOUND THAT HAS A BIG IMPACT.
```